# How to format numbers with commas after every 3 digits?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, textfield

I would like a `textfield` to format numbers with commas after every 3 digits.

I am using Swift-UI and my `Textfield` is binded to a String State var

I'm not sure how to apply a formatter to this textfield to ensure commas are automatically inserted where they need to go as the user is typing.

I understand there are other questions similar to this but I am unable to get it to work.

```
@State private var purchaseAmount: String = ""

TextField("Purchase Amount", text: $purchaseAmount)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.tertiarySystemFill))
                .cornerRadius(9)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

Thank you for your help.

I have found this snippet of code on another stack overflow question:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if ((string == "0" || string == "") && (textField.text! as NSString).range(of: ".").location < range.location) {
            return true
        }

        // First check whether the replacement string's numeric...
        let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
        let filtered = string.components(separatedBy: cs)
        let component = filtered.joined(separator: "")
        let isNumeric = string == component

        // Then if the replacement string's numeric, or if it's
        // a backspace, or if it's a decimal point and the text
        // field doesn't already contain a decimal point,
        // reformat the new complete number using
        if isNumeric {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
            // Combine the new text with the old; then remove any
            // commas from the textField before formatting
            let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            let numberWithOutCommas = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
            let number = formatter.number(from: numberWithOutCommas)
            if number != nil {
                var formattedString = formatter.string(from: number!)
                // If the last entry was a decimal or a zero after a decimal,
                // re-add it here because the formatter will naturally remove
                // it.
                if string == "." && range.location == textField.text?.count {
                    formattedString = formattedString?.appending(".")
                }
                textField.text = formattedString
            } else {
                textField.text = nil
            }
        }
        return false

    }
```

How do I apply this function to a TextField?

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain the issues.

Comment: Please refer to the edit in the question I have included some code

Comment: @meaning-matters

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a `Formatter` in `TextField` you need:

```
TextField("Purchase Amount", value: $purchaseAmount, formatter: numberFormatter)
```

And your formatter should look like this:

```
 let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return numberFormatter
}()
```

Comment: ok thanks, does that mean purchaseAmount needs to be of type Double or Int?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think so yes